# Canopy - Working With Select Lists

Tags: selenium-webdriver, f#, canopy-web-testing

I have just started working with Canopy and am struggling with select lists. I know you can set the selected item by value by doing:

```
"#dropDown" << read "option[value='x']"
```

However, how would you select the nth element of a select list> Or, how about selecting by text? I can't seem to find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got some good suggestions/answers here: https://github.com/lefthandedgoat/canopy/issues/176